# Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, fetch, error500

Necesito hacer un fetch y me salta este error, lei que se podia cambiar el JSON a la carpeta public, pero a mi me dice que no puedo usar nada fuera de src. Uso React

```
import array_productos from "./productos.json";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ItemList from "./ItemList"

const ItemListContainer = (greeting) => {

    const [productos, SetProductos] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('./productos.json')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw response;
        })
        .then(data => {
            array_productos = data  
            array_productos.then(productos => SetProductos(productos))          
        })        
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
            setError(error)            ;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
            });
     }, []);

    if (loading) return "Loading...";
    if (error) return "Error!";

    return(
        <div>      
            <ItemList productos={productos}/>
        </div>

        
    )
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que revisaría es la sintáxis de `productos.json`, puede que haya algún problema ¿Puedes agregar ese contenido? saludos